# How to set OnClickListener for textViews created dynamically?

Tags: android

I created rows of textViews and I'd like to make an OnClickListener so that when they are clicked, they return the text. I have something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    tv1.setText("Some text");

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //something should go here
    }

    tableLayout.addView(tv1);
}
```

What should I do so that when I do the onLongClick that I get a reference to the textView I'm selecting and not the last one I added? I can't just call tv1 inside the onLongClick because it's not static..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the listener on the `TextView` and use the parameter of the `onClick` callback:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    tv1.setText("Some text");
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              // v is the TextView that was clicked
              String theText =  ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
         }

    });
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a technique. If I understood your problem right, you could put all your dynamic TextViews inside an ArrayList. Like below

```
ArrayList<TextView> listTextView = new ArrayList<TextView>();

for (int=0; i<json.length; i++) {
     TextView textView = new TextView(this);
     textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     textView.setText("Some Text");
     textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           TextView text = (TextView) v;
           String theText = text.getText().toString();
         }

    });
    listTextView.add(textView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying this method, then running into problems.